# get record using if statment & pdo query in function php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have problem with function pdo, when it will take 1 record from the database, the result is null;

connect.php

```
<?php

class dbConn{

    protected static $db;

    private function __construct() {

        try {
            self::$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=item', 'root', '' );
            self::$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection Error " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    public static function getConnection() {

        if (!self::$db) {
            new dbConn();
        }

        return self::$db;
    }

}
?>
```

function.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
class ajax_table {

    function detailitem($table){
        $db = dbConn::getConnection();
        $sql = "select * from ".$table."" or die(mysql_error());
        $q = $db->query($sql) or die("failed!");
        $res = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $res;
        //else echo "No records found";
    }     
}
?>
```

and to display

displayitem.php

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
$url=$url.'.html';

include 'connect.php';
include 'function.php';
$db = dbConn::getConnection();
$obj = new ajax_table();
$records = $obj->detailitem('product WHERE url = "$url"');
if($records){
    echo $records['name'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $records['type'];
}else{
    echo 'no result';
 } ?>
```

database is not empty, but result display
no error, and also does not display anything

Comment: Why do you have `or die()` in a string assignment, and why is it calling `mysql_error()` when you're using PDO?

Comment: The first script is named `connection.php`, but you're including `connect.php`.

Comment: And the second sript is named `t_function.php`, but you're including `function.php`. Are you sure you have all the right files?

Comment: barmar : sorry for spelling mistakes, but the call file for me is right,I improve the writing.

Comment: why using or die() and calling mysql_error because i'm so confused and i'm new using PDO

Comment: do you know where is the problem?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem.

Comment: Does it display nothing, or does it display "no result"?

Comment: Your script is probably getting an error. Check your PHP error log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69497/discussion-between-riski-febriansyah-and-barmar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see correctly on the following line :

```
$records = $obj->detailitem('product WHERE url = "$url"');
```

It passes the  string as *"$url"* , not the value of `$url` variable.

So change it to :

```
$records = $obj->detailitem('product WHERE url = \''.$url.'\'');
```

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah Variables are expanded inside double quotes, but not inside single quotes. Your other select is probably using double quotes.

Comment: thanks barmar and Fev it's work, but i found the fatal error now "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'shoes' in 'where clause'' in line function.php $res = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); where actually the value of url is '/1234/shoes-small.html.

Comment: that means column "shoes" doesn't exist in your table.., you can check the column whether it exists or not by typing `DESC yourTableName` in your mysql terminal

Comment: yes right, no column 'shoes' in my table of database, 'shoes' is a record in url column. accutaly '/1234/shoes-small.html'

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah That sounds like you didn't quote the URL, so it treated `shoes` as a column name instead of being in a string.